# how can I use switch case into Ajax response/convert string to array into Ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

into my ajax response I got this value:

```
orderDetail: Array(1)
0:
area_name: "Barisal Sadar"
city_name: "Barisal"
email: "namixypi@mailinator.com"
fname: "Ivana"
id: 6
lname: "Rocha"
message: null
pay_type: "Bkash"
phone: "017845698532"
pick_up_date: "2021-09-21"
pick_up_time: null
required_services: "1,2,3"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I have three checkboxes when I insert required_services values into the database I send it as a string. Now I need to fetch the data and show them by name. Where 1 for Iron, 2 for Dry Wash and 3 for Wash. I am using Ajax. How can I show them by Name using Ajax.

My Ajax Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#viewOrder', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let orderId = $(this).val();
                // alert(orderId);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/getOrder/" + orderId,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('#orderTablemodal tbody').html('');
                       $.each(response.orderDetail, function(key, item) {

                            $('#orderTablemodal tbody').append(
                                '<tr>\
                                    <td><b>Customer Phone No.</b></td>\
                                    <td>'+item.phone+'</td>\
                                </tr>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <td><b>Customer Name: </b> </td>\
                                    <td>' + item.fname +' '+item.lname+'</td>\
                                </tr>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <td><b>E-mail: </b> </td>\
                                    <td>' + item.email +'</td>\
                                </tr>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <td><b>Location: </b></td>\
                                    <td>'+item.area_name+', '+item.city_name+'</td>\
                                </tr>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <td><b>Services :</b> </td>\
                                    <td>Iron*** Here I need to show my services name ****</td>\
                                </tr>\
                                <tr>\
                                    <td><b>Pay type: </b> </td>\
                                    <td>' + item.pay_type +'</td>\
                                </tr>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem right, use split:

```js
let string = "1,2,3";
console.log(string.split(","));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```